# Riddle - cover a $62 \times 66$ board using only $341$ straight rows of $12$ squares each

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

Is it possible to cover a $62 \times 66$ board using only $341$ straight rows of $12$ squares each?

Answer (score 4):

No.  Hint:  color $6 \times 6$ squares like a checkerboard.

Here is an example of a $18 \times 14$ board colored as I suggested.  Each square is $6 \times 6$ and the rectangles are $2 \times 6$.  The extension to $66 \times 62$ should be clear.  Note that there are more black squares than white squares, but that every $1 \times 12$ placing will cover $6$ of each.
[image]

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me the reason for this ? I'm sorry but I'm a law student and this is certainly out of my proficiency :)

Comment: @user75013:  Are you familiar with the proof that you cannot cover an $8 \times 8$ board missing two diagonally opposite corners with $31$ dominos?  You could look at [the mutilated chessboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem).  What combination of colors is covered by a $1 \times 12$ rectangle in my coloring?

Comment: Hi, no but I'm familiar with the 63 squares board that need to be covered with trominoes. anyway It would be nice to receive an explanation and not a hint. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user75013:  this is much simpler than the trominoes on a chess board and requires no more math than multiplication.

Comment: why will a 6X6 board be enough ? what am i trying to do with it ? coloring it ? what size of rows should i use now ? how many of them? its not clear !

Comment: @user75013:  No, you color the whole board like a chessboard, but each square of one color represents a $6 \times 6$ region.  So you will have $11 \times 10\frac 13$ squares.  At the last border, you will wind up with regions $2 \times 6$ squares.  Now argue that no matter where you put a $1 \times 12$ rectangle on this board it will cover six black and six white squares.

Comment: what do u mean by that last border? the last border of the imaginary 11X10⅓ or the last border of the current checkerboard?

Comment: @user75013  When you have done a $11 \times 10$ block of $6 \times 6$ squares, you will have covered a rectangle $66 \times 60$.  That leaves a strip of $2 \times 62$ at the end of the board.  Just continue the coloring with $2 \times 6$ rectangles that are part of the next set of squares.  It would be the same as if you started with a $66 \times 66$ rectangle, colored it, then cut off the last four columns.

Comment: Ross, are you assuming that any such tiling could be split into a tiling of a $66\times 60$ rectangle and a $66\times 2$ rectangle?  Might there be a tiling that doesn't split so nicely?  I believe not, but I'm not sure your proof rules out such a case.

Comment: @Jared:  No, I am defining a specific tiling that splits that way.  I just need one tiling that ensures that any $1 \times 12$ rectangle will cover $6$ squares of each color and has an unequal number of squares of each color.

Comment: Yes, I see.  You're right.  The key is that $11$ is odd.

Comment: @Jared:  that is right.

Comment: @Jared:  I posted a figure, but it sounds like you have it already.